# Why my Raspberry pi 3 model b is going crazy?

Tags: raspberry-pi3

My raspberry pi 3 model b is doing things automatically like opening browser and inspect elements ,taking screenshots  without my control.my os is noobs.Before noobs , i tried ubuntu mate 18.04.02, same problem persisted so i formatted  the sd card and again installed noobs but the problem still exist. Please somebody help me to resolve this.

Comment: If you unplug the keyboard/mouse, does it still happen?

Comment: I think so..because i am using wired usb keyboard -zebronics.

Comment: I am checking it...just a minute

Comment: If i un-plug the key board its working fine bro

Comment: If i disconnect the internet its working fine with keyboard

Comment: So what might be the problem bro?

Comment: Consider asking the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) community, they probably know a lot more over there ;)

Comment: Can you test the keyboard/mouse on another computer? Just a wild guess, but maybe one of them is faulty??

Comment: Yes i did it with my laptop .its completely fine

Answer (score 0):

Noobs is an installation manager not your OS.

If you disconnect your Pi from the internet, does it still happen?

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification and I am checking that too....just give me a minute

Comment: If i disconnect the internet its working fine with keyboard

Comment: So what might be the problem?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Hi Alejandro... i m using raspbian os